# nopCommerce 2.70 - Placing a topic as content above the Contact Us form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

This is a nopCommerce 2.70 related question.

I would like to add a few sentences above the "Contact Us" form but I don't want to hard code them in the ContactUs.cshtml file. I would like to be able to edit them in the back-end.

Is it possible to place a topic's content/text above the "Contact Us" form by calling a variable in the Contact us form's template or something like that? If so, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there's a very simple way to do this, by embedding a TopicBlock action into your .cshtml file, like so:

@Html.Action("TopicBlock", "Topic", new { systemName = "YourTopicSystemName" })

where "YourTopicSystemName" is the system name for a topic you've created in the admin. This will allow you or your designated users to update the content via the admin, without touching the files again.